# Python - Querying/Controlling multiple hosts across WAN link?

Tags: python, twisted, celery, tornado

We have several data-centres located in several countries (Japan, Hong Kong, Singapore etc.).

We run applications on multiple hosts at each of these locations - probably around 50-100 hosts in total.

I'm working on a Python script that queries the status of each application, sends various triggers to them, and retrieves other things from them during runtime. This script could conceivably query a central server, which would then send the request to an agent running on each host.

One of the requirements is that the script is as responsive as possible - e.g. if I query the status of applications on all hosts in all locations, I would like the result within 1-3 seconds, as opposed to 20-30 seconds.

Hence, querying each hosts sequentially would be too slow, particularly considering the WAN hops we'd need to make.

We can assume that the query on each host itself is fairly trivial (e.g. is process  running or not).

I'm fairly new to concurrent programming or asynchronous programming, so would value any input at all here. What is the "best" approach to tackling this problem?

- Use a multi-threaded or multi-process approach - e.g. spawn a new thread for each host, send them all out, then wait for replies?
- Use asyncore, twisted, tornado - any comments on which if any are suitable here? (I get the impression that asyncore isn't that popular. Tornado might be fun to try, but not sure how it could be used here?)
- Use some kind of message queue (e.g. Kombu/RabbitMQ)?
- Use celery, somehow? Would it be responsive enough for the responsive times we want? (e.g. under 3 seconds for the above).

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use [`gevent`](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#installation).

### How?

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_socket() # So anything socket-based now works asynchronously. 
#This should be the first line of you code!
import gevent

def query_server(server_ip):
    # do_something with server_ip and sockets

server_ips = [....]
jobs = [gevent.spawn(query_server, server_ip) for server_ip in server_ips]
gevent.joinall(jobs)
print [job.result for job in jobs]
```

### Why bother?

- All your code will run in a **single process and a single thread**. This means you won't have to bother with locks, semaphores and message passing.
- Your task seems to be mostly network-bound. Gevent will **let you do network-bound work asynchronously**, which means your code won't busy-wait on network connections, and instead will let OS notify it when the data is received.
- It's a personal preference, but I think that `gevent` is the **easiest asynchronous library to use when you want to do one-off work**. (Like, you don't have to start a `reactor` a-la `twisted`).

### Will it work?

The response-time will be the response time of your slowest server.
If using `gevent` doesn't do it, then you'll have to fix your network.

Comment: Hmm, I'll need something listening at the other end to actually listen for the request, then query process status, send various SIGs to the process etc. - could I use gevent for that side of it as well?

Comment: @victorhooi As I mentionned, raw `gevent` is really easy for one-off jobs, which is the client-side. For the server-side, a `twisted` / `tornado` daemon would work, but [`gevent` can do it too](http://www.gevent.org/servers.html)!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), especially the `map()` or `map_async()` members.

Write a function that takes a single argument (e.g. the hostname, or a list/tuple of hostname and other data. Let that function query a host and return relevant data.

Now compule a list of input variables (hostnames), and use `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` or `multiprocessing.Pool.map_async()` to execute the functions in parallel. The `async` variant will start returning data sooner, but there is a limit to the amount of work you can do in a callback.

This will automatically use as many cores as your machine has to process the functions in parallel.

If there are network delays however, there is not much the python program can do about that.